# Hybris ant all is failing in eclipse while building the below target in build.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, sap-commerce-cloud

I have installed SAP Hybris commerce plugin in eclipse and am trying to do ant all, but then am facing issue at the below target:

```
    <target name="build" depends="updateMavenDependencies" description="Builds all extensions">
        <callback extname="" target="before_build"/>
        <build/>
        <callback extname="" target="after_build"/>
    </target>
```

However am able to build through command line.

But for debugging purposes, I want my eclipse to build the project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new build.xml base on projekt in eclipse.

`Select File > Export`

from main menu

Next Export dialog, select

`General > Ant Buildfiles`

and try run new build.xml